# Migrate RDS to Aurora MySQL with Ruby on rails Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-aurora

I have a Ruby On Rails App on Elastic Beanstalk with MySQL RDS, and I want to migrate it to Aurora MySQL, I could migrate my database and I have the new endpoint of Aurora MySQL, I first tried to connect it in my development environment to check if everything was going good, but when I try to deploy in production I got an error by elastic beanstalk "12_db_migration.sh failed.", but It does not have sense because I connected the database in development and It worked, It looks like if elastic beanstalk couldn't connect to the database, all credentials are correct. There are not pending migrations, and the error message does not have sense. Something important is that my previous MySQL version is 5.7.24 and the MySQL version of my new Aurora MySQL database is 5.7.12, but I think It doesn't matter because in development worked well.

Thank you.

Comment: When you get the error reported by elastic beanstalk stating "12_db_migration.sh failed." what reason does it give you for the failure? Check your log files maybe there is a clue there

Comment: thank you, This is the error: ' Error in `/opt/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/bin/rake db:migrate': malloc(): memory corruption: 0x00005643b34ce420'

Comment: Sounds like not enough memory available in the environment that is being used to run the migration. So maybe you should try again with a larger memory allocation. How much memory are you making available?

Comment: In the instance I have 3.6Gb available, I have 8Gb in total.

Comment: Hhmm! That's not a lot, Perhaps up it to 10gb just to run the migration. You can always drop it down after but I tend to use a min of 10gb in production but you need to at least double it and try again.

Comment: okay, I could fix it, the problem was that I was written my credentials in database.yml file without using environment variables, I was testing something and I didn't use environment variables, and It looks that I cannot do that, I use environment variables in the file and everything worked. Thank you!

Comment: Glad you got it sorted, you should answer and accept your question so that others facing this issue will see the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay, I could fix it, the problem was that I was written my credentials in database.yml file without using environment variables, I was testing something and I didn't use environment variables, and It looks that I cannot do that, I use environment variables in the file and everything worked.